# Java Vowel count using Collection

Tags: java, collections

I am asked to write a code to count and display vowels in a String using Sets. Any suggestions as to why the code below gives wrong output? Switch seemed like the obvious approach, I also tried with an if-statemen, but neither work properly.

```
import java.util.*;

class Vowels {
String s;   
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
Vowels(String s, LinkedHashSet<String> set) {
    this.s = s;
    this.set = set;
}
public void evaluator() {  
    Collections.addAll(set, s.split(""));
    int vn = 0;
    String vowel = "";
    List<String> vowels = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        switch(it.next()) {
        case "a":
        case "e":
        case "i":
        case "o":
        case "u":
        case "y":
        case "w": 
            vn++;       
            vowel = it.next();
            vowels.add(vowel);  
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of vowels is " + vn);
    System.out.println("Vowels are " + vowels);
}
}

public class ExXVI {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedHashSet<String> set1 = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    Vowels q = new Vowels("Some words have vowels, some do not", set1);
    q.evaluator();
}
} /* Output:
Number of vowels is 4
Vowels are [m,  , r, v]
*///:~
```

Comment: Seems pretty convoluted. Also since when "w" is a vowel?!

Comment: For now I said I'll go with 'y' and 'w' as vowels.

Comment: `w` is **not** a vowel in the Latin system (i.e. English). It may be defined as [approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximant_consonant) in some languages.

Comment: Y is a vowel in very many languages (but not English). I believe w is a vowel in Welsh (Twm is a Welsh first name).

Comment: @OleV.V. Y is *sometimes* a vowel in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's partially because you're counting 'Y' and 'W' as vowels. Also, when you go to save the vowel, you call it.next() again. This actually gets the next object in the collection, not the one you just compared in the switch. You should save the value of it.next() before the switch, then use the variable to reference it later.

Comment: `y` **is** a vowel.

Comment: @StaticShadow Thank you very much. It works now. I obviously didn't realize that each time I call .next(), the cursor moves to the next item in the list.

Comment: @Andy if this was the answer that solved your issue, it would be appreciated if you chose it as accepted.

Comment: @Andy There should be a big check mark you can click on the left under the up and down arrows. Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are missing some vowels is that you are using a `Set` which does not allow duplicate entries. Besides that you also call twice `it.next()` and thus losing the previous entry. I modified your code a bit by removing the `Sets` but still using your concept.

```
class Vowels {
    String s;

    Vowels(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void evaluator() {
        int vn = 0;
        String vowel = "";
        List<String> vowels = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> vowelsList = Arrays.asList(s.split(""));
        Iterator<String> it = vowelsList.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            vowel = it.next();
            switch (vowel) {
                case "a":
                case "e":
                case "i":
                case "o":
                case "u":
                case "y":
                case "w":
                    vn++;
                    vowels.add(vowel);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of vowels is " + vn);
        System.out.println("Vowels are " + vowels);
    }
}

public class ExXVI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vowels q = new Vowels("Some words have vowels, some do not");
        q.evaluator();
    }
}
```

Will print the following:

```
Number of vowels is 13
Vowels are [o, e, w, o, a, e, o, w, e, o, e, o, o]
```

Comment: w is not a vowel.

Comment: @aUserHimself Yes, but the OP wants to have them as vowels. As it does not restrict the functionality at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8 you could use streams:

```
long numberOfVowels = input.toLowerCase().chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
                     .filter(c -> "aeiou".contains(String.valueOf(c)))
                     .count();
```

There is a semantic problem though; ['y' is sometimes a vowel and sometimes a consonant](https://www.spellzone.com/unit03/quest2/index.cfm), depending on the word it occurs in.

Comment: `Arrays.stream()` accepts an array of references (an array of generic type `T`), not a `char` array. `String.contains()` accepts a `CharSequence`, not a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

The vowels in English are [A, E, I, O, U] and sometimes Y, according to this [wiki page](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel).

I have fixed your solution:

```
class Vowels {
String s;   
List<String> list;

Vowels(String s, List<String> list) {
    this.s = s;
    this.list = list;
}

public void evaluator() {  
    Collections.addAll(list, s.split(""));
    int vn = 0;
    String vowel;
    List<String> vowels = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        vowel = it.next();
        System.out.println("Vowel is: " + vowel);
        switch(vowel) {
        case "a":
        case "e":
        case "i":
        case "o":
        case "u":
        case "y":
            vn++;
            vowels.add(vowel);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of vowels is " + vn);
    System.out.println("Vowels are " + vowels);
}
}

class ExXVI {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Vowels q = new Vowels("Some words have vowels, some do not", list);
    q.evaluator();
}
}
```

Actual response:

```
Number of vowels is 11
Vowels are [o, e, o, a, e, o, e, o, e, o, o]
```

Be aware that `Set` does not allow duplicate entries, so the result of splitting the string should be stored into a `List`. Also, in your code, calling `it.next()` twice will cause your program to skip counting some vowels, as `next()` changes the current element by moving to right into the `Collection`.

`Set` is useful if you want to keep all unique vowels that appear in your string, so you might want to use:

```
Set<String> vowels = new HashSet<String>();
```

which results in

```
Number of vowels is 11
Vowels are [a, e, o]
```

Comment: In the meantime I did that, but thanks anyway for the concern. Yes, I was thinking the same thing about Sets(no duplicates) and Lists(can have duplicates), but that is not the main issue in this case

Answer (score -3):

```
long count = str.chars().filter(ch->"aeiou".contains((char)ch+"")).count();
```